# duplicate entry issue with large mysql database table

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have a very large MySQL database table. The other day, for no apparent reason, I now keep getting:

`Duplicate entry '148245' for key 'PRIMARY'`

If I remove the entry at with primary of `148245`, then I just get the same error but showing a different number. I tried on a backup copy of the table by removing the bad row and trying an insert statement through my ASP.NET webpage using the MySQL connector which has until recently always worked and I get the error but with a different number.

What do I do to remove this error - surely I can't just delete a load of rows until it goes away?

Not an error I have seen before and I am not a massive MySQL expert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? What is the type of the PRIMARY KEY? Please add exactly what queries you are executing to the database, this seems like an error on the programming side (you are trying to insert an row that already exists), not a database error.

Comment: Add the query. It seems there is some mistake in your query.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13132650/470530) - take a *dump* of the table, *drop* it and recreate it. Reload your *dump* - that solved the issue here. If this doesn't solve the issue, then please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` and also the contents of *my.cnf*.